# What web framework is this for?

Tags: javascript, .net, visual-studio, webserver

I'm trying to help a friend identify the web framework her company's using, but having a real tough time despite ample Googling. This is a screenshot she sent me:

[image]

Example searchs:

- IOS webserver
- IOS model view templates
- SqlProcs
- MSBuild.Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.targets.12.0.1
- Microsoft Web Publishing
- Newtonsoft

I can't figure out if Microsoft is just from having used Visual Studio to develop a website, or Microsoft has some kind of a framework (integrated with Visual Studio). *templates* has some HTML files; otherwise, nothing.

I'm used to Apache and Nginx, and this is just boggling my mind. Where does this publish its final files to? What kind of an environment?

Comment: Come on, SO. RTFA / FAQ before downvoting. From [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic): _"software tools commonly used by programmers; and is a practical, answerable problem that is unique to software development"_. Despite knowing Javascript, HTML/CSS, SQL, some MVC via Rails, and some Visual Studio, I can't identify how this website deploys. There is a webmasters SE, but this might have more to do with a company's unique development toolchain (or maybe common!), _e.g._ using TFS for source control.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the chrome extension Wappalyzer? https://wappalyzer.com/